# how to dry out flavored sugar

Tags: storage-method, drying

Hi I just wanted to know how to dry out flavored sugar, I flavored some regular white sugar with flavoring essence but it got damp, since where I'm from its hard to get these types of sugar so I was thinking of selling some. But when I put it in a bag after air drying its still damp and it gets clumpy and has hard patches. How can I dry it out completely without ruining the flavor?

Answer (score 2):

1. Place sugar on baking sheet spread out
2. Place into oven on the lowest temperature for 30 minutes or until no longer damp*
3. Remove from oven and let cool
4. Place into bags the amount you plan to sell
5. Break up any clumps by pinching the clumps in the sealed bag

*if you used an excessive amount of flavoring, you may need to add more plain sugar to the mix.

Comment: Instead of the lowest temperature, which might be too hot in places (depending on a number of factors) you could turn the oven on for a while, then turn it off and use the *warm* oven to dry your sugar.  You can even heat up and use the cooling oven in cycles, to keep the temperature gentle for even extended drying times.

Comment: One common trick where I come from is to put the handle of a wooden spoon or spatular in the oven door so it stays slightly open, then turn the oven on the lowest heat with convection. The convection will constantly blow warm air around the baking tray and the moisture can evaporate through the gap in the door.